# Is there a way (or a plugin) to make Vim generate a code outline for CSS?

Tags: css, vim, plugins, tags, outline

I was trying to install taglist (but I couldn't install ctags), but I realized that it doesn't support css, is there another way or plugin to perform this job?

PS: I checked the install file of ctags, but I couldn't find any steps which looked like an installation manual.

it just says:

```
Installation Notes
==================

For non-Unix platforms, simple makefiles are provided:

    descrip.mms   For VMS using either DEC C or VAX C
    mk_bc3.mak    For MSDOS using Borland C/C++ 3.x
    mk_bc5.mak    For Win32 using Borland C++ 5.5
    mk_djg.mak    For MSDOS using DJGPP Gnu GCC (better to follow Unix install)
    mk_manx.mak   For Amiga using Aztec/Manx C 5.0
    mk_mingw.mak  For Win32 using MinGW
    mk_mpw.mak    For Macintosh using MPW
    mk_mvc.mak    For Win32 using Microsoft Visual C++
    mk_os2.mak    For OS/2 using GCC (EMX)
    mk_qdos.mak   For QDOS using C68
    mk_riscos.mak For RISC OS using the GCC SDK <http://hard-mofo.dsvr.net>
    mk_sas.mak    For Amiga using SAS/C
```

There's a complited ctag.exe. What I'm suppose to do with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Consider using code folding instead](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/114138).  It's similar to outlining, in that you have fewer lines to look at to get an idea of the overall structure, but it hides most of the code until you unfold the part you want to read in detail or edit.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was considering that, but everyone was talking about taglist and I thought it was some sort of magic plugin.

Answer (score 8):

To expand [Conspicuous Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106769/conspicuous-compiler)'s good suggestion, you can try this (I do it often):

```
:set foldmethod=marker
:set foldmarker={,}
```

which, assuming your definitions are in this form:

```
#topbar {
    ....
}
```

automatically gives a view like this:

```
+--  5 lines: body -----------------------
+-- 12 lines: #topbar --------------------
+--  4 lines: #topbar input --------------
+--  4 lines: #topbar li -----------------
....
```

i.e. one line per block, expandable on request.