# How to browse SASS/CSS files with VIM effectively?

Tags: vim, sass

Smartest minds in this sector of internet!
Please advise me how to effectively browse codebase in SASS with VIM.
Tagbar not showing SASS tree, neither I can fold style declarations hierarchically.
So, the question is - how to use tagbar and/or folding with SASS/SCSS/CSS files?
Maybe you can suggest me other way of effectively browsing SASS?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**Folding**

With `set foldenable` and `set foldmethod=indent` in your `~/.vimrc`, you are able to fold away all the definitions with `zM` and go back to normal with `zR`. Use `zj` and `zk` to jump from fold to fold. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2132691/546861) for a very cool tip that I'm going to use *right now* and `:help fold` for more info about folding.

**Tags**

See [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12924218/546861) for a limited [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)-based solution. And [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/1527856) for an approach using [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/). That's what you need to try first if you want a hierarchical tree with your classes, ids and tagnames.

**Cscope**

You won't get a hierarchical tree or an outline with it but [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) is a great code indexer that may be useful for jumping directly to a known selector. Do `$ cscope -R *.scss` and search for classes, ids and tagnames. Hit `<CR>` on a match to open your `$EDITOR` at the correct line.

---

I personnaly use the "limited ctags-based solution" above with [CtrlP](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/)'s `:CtrlPBufTag` and `:CtrlpTag` with great success. But I only do basic CSS.

Comment: Have been looking for a solution for this also, could you elaborate on how did you installed the assets necessary for the ctags based solution?